# Adding RazorFormat is giving error in ServiceStack

Tags: razor, servicestack

I tried to add RazorFormat into my ServiceStack Project using Nuget Package Manager but it is not getting added properly.Adding of RazorFormat like this is creating lot of error into my Solution. So i downloaded the `ServiceStack.Razor.4.0.46` and added as reference manually and it got added. Now to use Razor i am trying to add it as Plugin into my `Global.asax.cs` like this ..

```
Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());
```

Here i am getting the best overloaded method have some invalid argument error on compile time.

How to resolve this ?

Comment: No one can guess what errors you're getting are, so you need to show them, i.e. Screenshots/StackTraces, etc. Did you register the Plugin in your ServiceStack AppHost? The easiest way to create a project with Razor is to create a new **ServiceStack ASP.NET with Razor** in the [ServiceStackVS](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStackVS) VS.NET Extension, you can also create an empty template to compare it with you're doing wrong.

Comment: @mythz Okay So i tried to register the plugin inside `public AeraEnergyServicesAppHost()
                : base("AeraEnergy Services", typeof(EntryService).Assembly)
            { Plugins.Add(new RazorFormat());}`. Still i am getting `the best overloaded method have some invalid argument error`

Comment: All plugins should be registered in your `AppHost.Configure()`, please refer to the [LiveDemos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos) projects for working configuration, e.g. [Chat is a small, simple App with Razor](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/Chat/blob/master/src/Chat/Global.asax.cs#L30).

Comment: @mythz I double checked to make sure that i am adding the plugin inside `Configure` itself

Comment: Please refer to existing working examples I've provided above. I can only assume you've registered it incorrectly but cannot guess what without seeing any error, source code, project dependencies, etc. Compare your code with the working Live Demo examples otherwise create a new project template in SSVS which has everything pre-registered for you.

Comment: @mythz Okay ..I tried to rebuild the solution and Now i am getting an error as `Warning 1 Reference to type 'ServiceStack.IPlugin' claims it is defined in 'd:\Services\packages\ServiceStack.3.9.25\lib\net35\ServiceStack.dll', but it could not be found d:Services\packages\ServiceStack.Razor.4.0.46\lib\net45\ServiceStack.Razor.dll AeraEnergyServices..Any Suggestion for this ?
`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91747/discussion-between-lara-and-mythz).

Comment: I've left an answer on the issue referencing incompatible packages. In future please provide all relevant information as this is impossible and time consuming to guess without being provided any context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is because you're trying to reference an incompatible **3.9.25** dll (that's over 3 years old) with this months latest **v4.0.46**. You need to make sure the versions of all your ServiceStack packages have exactly the same version.

Remove and re-add ServiceStack NuGet packages to all your projects, then delete your `/packages` folder and after a NuGet package restore make sure that you only have the same version in your `/packages` folder, if you don't it means some of your projects is referencing incompatible versions.

If you want to use the legacy v3 of ServiceStack please refer to the [ServiceStack V3 Home Page](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3) for instructions on installing, uninstalling and updating NuGet packages.